# How do I call gapi.client.firebase.projects.iosApp.create with the correct arguments?

Tags: firebase, google-api-js-client

I've authenticated and gotten as far as programmatically setting up a GCP project, followed by adding Firebase management and adding a Firebase project.

Finally, I want to be able to call: `https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/myProject/iosApps` but I get a **400 invalid arguments error**.

It doesn't say *which argument*, so I've been trying with the API explorer to try each one, but with no luck

```js
export async function addAppDetails(project) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  await gapi.client.firebase.projects.iosApps
    .create({
      parent: `projects/${project.id}`,
      resource: {
        name: **something here?**,
        appId: **something here?**,
        displayName: project.appName,
        projectId: project.id,
        appStoreId: "",
        bundleId: `com.company.${project.appName.replace(/\s+/, '').toLowerCase()}`,
      },
    })
    .then(operation => operation.result);
}
```

The API says I should pass a valid IosApp object: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.iosApps#IosApp

```js
{
  "name": string,
  "appId": string,
  "displayName": string,
  "projectId": string,
  "bundleId": string,
  "appStoreId": string
}
```

But it also says `appId` is generated *by Firebase* and `name` contains `appId`.
This seems like a circular dependency? 
How do I get an appId without creating an app, that needs an appId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the documentation is wrong.

You should **only** send `displayName` and `bundleId`, not a full `IosApp` object, otherwise you will get a 400 error.